# Expected declaration on switch declaration

Tags: swift

I'm writing this switch block of code inside a structure and I'm getting a compile error I have not seen before.

```
public struct beltRank {
    var rank: Int?

    switch rank { // Compile Error: 'Expected Declaration'
    case 1:
        self.belt = "White"
    case 2:
        self.belt = "White I"
    case 3:
        self.belt = "White II"
    case 4:
        self.belt = "White III"
    .
    .
    .

    case 21:
        self.belt = "Black"
    default:
        self.belt = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `switch` needs to be in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write `switch rank {` inside the struct directly , it should be inside a function `init` or any other custom one

```
public struct beltRank {
  var rank = 0
  var belt = ""
  init(rank:Int) {
    // write switch here
  }
}
```